# pr not triggered when opening github PR (Azure pipeline YAML)

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

## The goal

I'm pretty new to Azure and pipelines, and I'm trying to trigger a pipeline from a **pr** in Azure. The repo lives in Github.

Here is the pipeline yaml: **pipeline.yml**

```yaml
trigger: none # I turned this off for to stop push triggers (but they work fine)

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - "*" # This does not trigger the pipeline 

stages:
  - stage: EchoTriggerStage
    displayName: Echoing trigger reason
    jobs:
      - job: A
        steps:
          - script: echo 'Build reason::::' $(Build.Reason)
            displayName: The build reason

# ... some more stages here triggered by PullRequests....
# ... some more stages here triggered by push (CI)....
```

The pr on Github looks like this:
[image]

## The problem

However, the pipeline is not triggered, when the push triggers work just fine.

I have read in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) but I can't see why this does not work.

The pipeline is working perfectly fine when I am triggering it through `git push`. However, when I try to trigger it with PR's from Github, nothing happens. In the code above, I tried turning off push triggers, and allow for all pr's to trigger the pipeline. Still nothing.

I do not want to delete the pipeline yet and create a new one.

## Update

I updated the yaml file to work as suggested underneath. Since the pipeline actually runs through a push command now, the rest of the details of the yaml file are not relevant and are left out.

## Other things I have tried

- Opening new PR on Github
- Closing/Reopening PR on Github
- Making change to existing PR on Github

-> Still no triggering of pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to go to Azure Pipelines -> Edit pipeline -> Triggers -> Enable PR validation.

Comment: `Enable PR validation` does not seem to exist anymore - any ideas? I am using Azure Git repo not GitHub, may be this is why it is missing...

Answer (score 4):

You have a mistake in your pipeline. It should be like this:

```yaml
trigger: none # turned off for push

pr:
  - feature/automated-testing

steps:
- script: echo "PIPELINE IS TRIGGERED FROM PR"
```

Please change this

```yaml
  - stage:
      - script: echo "PIPELINE IS TRIGGERED FROM PR"
```

to

```
  - stage:
    jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
      - script: echo "PIPELINE IS TRIGGERED FROM PR"
```

**EDIT**

I used your pipeline

```yaml
trigger: none # I turned this off for to stop push triggers (but they work fine)

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - "*" # This does not trigger the pipeline 

stages:
  - stage: EchoTriggerStage
    displayName: Echoing trigger reason
    jobs:
      - job: A
        steps:
          - script: echo 'Build reason::::' $(Build.Reason)
            displayName: The build reason

# ... some more stages here triggered by PullRequests....
# ... some more stages here triggered by push (CI)....
```

and all seems to be working.

Here is [PR](https://github.com/kmadof/so-dojo.pr/pull/1) and here [build for it](https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/DevOps%20Manual/_build/results?buildId=8061&view=results)

[image]

I didn't do that but you can try to enforce this via branch policy. TO do that please go to repo settings and then as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below steps to troubleshooting your pipeline.

1, First you need to make sure a pipeline was created from the yaml file on azure devops Portal. See [example](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/yaml/#task-3-adding-a-yaml-build-definition) in this tutorial.

2, Below part of your yaml file is incorrect. `- script` task should be under `steps` section.

Change:

```
stages:
- stage:
    - script: echo "PIPELINE IS TRIGGERED FROM PR"
```

To:

```
 stages:
 - stage:
   jobs:
   - job:
     step:
     - script: echo "PIPELINE IS TRIGGERED FROM PR"
```

3, I saw you used template in your yaml file. Please make sure the template yaml files are in correct format. For example:

the `dockerbuild-dashboard-client.yml` template of yours is a [step template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#step-templates). You need to make sure its contents is like below:

```
parameters:
...
steps:
- script: echo "task 1"
- script:  echo "task 2"
```

And `webapprelease-dashboard-dev-client.yml` of yours is a [job template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#job-templates). Its contents should be like below:

```
parameters:
  name: ''
  pool: ''
  sign: false

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.name }}
  pool: ${{ parameters.pool }}
  steps:
  - script: npm install
  - script: npm test
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.sign, 'true') }}:
    - script: sign
```

4, After the pipeline was created on azure devops Portal. You can manually run this pipeline to make sure there is no error in the yaml file and the pipeline can be successfully executed.

5, If All above are checked, but the PR trigger still is not working. You can try deleting the pipeline(created on the first step) created on Azure devops portal and recreated a new pipeline from the yaml file.

Comment: Thanks. The pipeline is running on Azure with `trigger:` now from `git push`, so the syntax should be ok. The PR is still not working however..

Comment: @meerkat I copied your updated yaml. The pr trigger worked perfectly on my side. Could you have a try deleting the pipeline definition from azure pipeline(not the yaml file in github). And recreate a new one. It is very easy to recreate a pipeline definition from an existing azure-pipelines.yml file.

Comment: @meerkat You need to make sure the azure-pipelines.yml file exists in the pr target branch too.

Comment: the `azure-pipelines.yml` file exists in both the target and base branch. By deleting the pipeline defenition, do you mean deleting the whole pipeline in **Pipelines**? And creating the same one from the yaml?

Comment: @meerkat Yes, delete the pipeline definition in Pipelines. And create the same one from the yaml.

Answer (score 0):

Very bad. I've been experiencing a lot of hiccups with Azure overall.

Turning off `Limit building pull requests from forked GitHub repositories` enabled PR trigger of pipeline.

Under your devops organization:

[image]

[image]

This is very bad bec supposedly this setting is PR from a forked repo and not from a check out from the same branch.

Comment: Seems like this is a non well-thought-off change from Azure team if this can be disabled with "Enable PR validation" before as mentioned here. This is my 2nd time looking for a setting that supposedly were easy to configure given answers in forums but totally invalid anymore.